# How do i compare ordinal score across two or more categories?

Tags: chi-squared-test, ordinal-data, association-measure

I have an ordinal score ranging from ( 1 to 5 ) called "Score"

I have another binary variable Human Response (Yes or No ) called "h_score"

I don't think i can do correlation study in this case as the h_score isn't numeric or ordinal and hence correlation doesn't make sense.

How do i analyze if there is difference in distribution of **score** across **h_score** ? Can I use chi square test ?

Comment: Chi-square is fine so long as you meet some requirements about minimum cell frequency.

Comment: Thanks @DemetriPananos. Also,  can I use logit model to look into the coefficients ?

Comment: If you wanted to model h_score as a function of score, then yes.  If you wanted to use model score as a function of h_score, you would need a multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: For a binary variable, characyeristics like numeric/continuous/ordinal/... are really unimportant, correlation might well make sense ...

Comment: @DemetriPananos If you do not meet the requirements for  Chi-Square independence test you have to use [Fisher exact test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/fisher.test.html)

Comment: Similar:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270184/how-to-analyze-binary-categorical-vs-ordinal-data, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38548/how-do-you-estimate-correlations-between-ordinal-and-binary-data-in-spss, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442617/kendalls-tau-for-two-binary-variables, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436942/how-to-test-correlation-between-ordinal-and-a-binary-variable, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100414/how-do-you-correlate-binary-ordinal-variables, ...

Comment: ... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369783/how-to-do-a-correlation-matrix-with-categorical-ordinal-and-interval-variable/370067#370067, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/449175/how-to-find-out-if-there-is-any-correlation-between-a-yes-no-question-and-likert/449187#449187, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables/102800#102800

Comment: The first thing you can do is to compare the distributions of $Score$ between the $h\_score$. To do this you can make bar plots (one for $score$ for the group that answered $yes$, and one for group who answered $no$) and simply compare them. If some clear difference is visible then it answers your question wether $Score$ differs in people who answered $yes$ and $no$. To confirm this you can perform some goodness of fit test (Chi-square test for example). If your question is: does answer $yes$ o $no$ influences the $Score$, then you can perform some independence test.